# How can I use the AccessAnalyzer list_findings() function with boto3 in Python and understand the 'eq', 'neq', and 'contains' parameters?

Tags: aws-iam-access-analyzer

I have python programme issue, please help me to fix it.
This is for Access Analyzer - list_findings using boto3.
I want to list the findings for AWS IAM Role
Couldn't understand eq, neq and contains parameters in Access Analyzer.
Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('accessanalyzer')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
  response = client.list_findings(
    analyzerArn='string',
    filter={
        'string': {
            'eq': [
                'string',
            ],
            'neq': [
                'string',
            ],
            'contains': [
                'string',
            ],
            'exists': True|False
        }
    },
    sort={
        'attributeName': 'string',
        'orderBy': 'ASC'|'DESC'
    },
    nextToken='string',
    maxResults=123
)

Comment: This is the code what it should be in the access analyzer...